# Extract certain values of same parameter name from endpoint

Tags: angular

I have an endpoint that returns me a set of data. I am trying to extract just the `schemeNo` from this. The data can have one or more `schemeNo`.

Here is the data. The `schemeNo` resides within the `retirementData` set

```
{
  "id": "2193e640-d97c-4952-a8a4-9aa250db364a",
  "parentCorporate": null,
  "statusId": 2,
  "primaryColour": "#001aff",
  "riskData": "{\"packages\":[{\"id\":0,\"isMaxInCurrency\":false,\"max\":10.0,\"name\":\"Dual Risk\",\"riskPackageCoverId\":0,\"riskPackageCoverName\":null,\"packageCovers\":null,\"isPaidFromRetirementContributions\":false,\"isEnabled\":false}]}",
  "retirementData": "{\"benefits\":[{\"availableBenefitOptions\":{\"anniversaryDate\":\"2020-11-17T22:00:00Z\",\"hasPensionBackedHomeLoan\":false,\"retirementAge\":65,\"schemeName\":\"Dual Alexander Forbes Retirement Fund Pension Base Fund\",\"schemeNo\":\"1590\"},\"contribution\":{\"anniversaryDate\":null,\"employerContributions\":null,\"hasEmployerContribution\":false,\"hasMemberContribution\":true,\"hasVoluntaryContribution\":false,\"memberContributions\":[5.0],\"voluntaryContributions\":null},\"investmentStrategy\":{\"defaultOptionId\":0.0,\"hasClarity\":null,\"hasSinglePortfolio\":true,\"isComprehensive\":null,\"isLifestage\":null,\"lifestage\":null,\"portfolioOptionId\":null,\"defaultLabelName\":\"Single portfolio – Real Return Focus\"},\"qualifyingMembers\":{\"hasContract\":false,\"hasDisabilityClaims\":false,\"isFullTime\":true,\"isOverRetirementAge\":false,\"isPartTime\":false,\"isPermanent\":false,\"isUnderRetirementAge\":false}},{\"availableBenefitOptions\":{\"anniversaryDate\":\"2020-11-24T22:00:00Z\",\"hasPensionBackedHomeLoan\":false,\"retirementAge\":65,\"schemeName\":\"Dual Alexander Forbes Retirement Fund Pension Base Fund\",\"schemeNo\":\"2421\"},\"contribution\":{\"anniversaryDate\":null,\"employerContributions\":null,\"hasEmployerContribution\":false,\"hasMemberContribution\":true,\"hasVoluntaryContribution\":false,\"memberContributions\":[7.0],\"voluntaryContributions\":null},\"investmentStrategy\":{\"defaultOptionId\":0.0,\"hasClarity\":null,\"hasSinglePortfolio\":true,\"isComprehensive\":null,\"isLifestage\":null,\"lifestage\":null,\"portfolioOptionId\":null,\"defaultLabelName\":\"Single portfolio – Real Return Focus\"},\"qualifyingMembers\":{\"hasContract\":false,\"hasDisabilityClaims\":false,\"isFullTime\":true,\"isOverRetirementAge\":false,\"isPartTime\":false,\"isPermanent\":false,\"isUnderRetirementAge\":false}}],\"fundSalaryOptions\":[5.0]}",
  "createdDate": "2020-11-10T06:32:27.54Z",
  "modifiedDate": "2020-11-10T06:32:27.54Z",
  "subGroups": []
}
```

I tried the following but it only returns the first `schemeNo`

```
console.log(JSON.parse(resp["retirementData"])["benefits"]["0"].availableBenefitOptions.schemeNo);
```

If I remove the `[0]` it given an undefined error

Comment: You should be using `map` function there :`["benefits"].map(r=> r.availableBenefitOptions.schemeNo)`

Comment: thank you, you can put is as the answer an I'll mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since `benefits` property is an array and there is a possibility that it may contain more than 1 value then you should be using `Array.map` instead of indexed access. So your code should look like this :

```
console.log(
     JSON.parse(
       resp["retirementData"])["benefits"].map(r=> r.availableBenefitOptions.schemeNo));
```